# How could you cast a shared pointer to a class to a shared pointer to its child class when you are sure that this object points to that childs class?

Tags: c++, casting, parent-child, shared-ptr

```
class Parent{
    //some attributes
}
class Child: public Parent{
    //same attributes as parent and some more
    void childFunction();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Parent> vector;
}
```

Now during the reading of the vector I know that some pointers in the vector point to Child elements using the function typeId(). But How do I access the 'childFunction()' as an extracted element will have type Parent according to the compiler?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

Comment: use std::dynamic_pointer_cast, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/

Comment: `//same attributes as parent and some more` suggests I give a warning: The attributes of `Parent` will automatically be in `Child`. Do not reproduce them in `Child`.

Comment: Mind freak: Because inheritance in C++ is an [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a), `Child` is a `Parent`, which does not describe the usual relationship between parent and child. Because of this it's better if you use the terms *Base* and *Derived*.

Comment: Do you know what virtual methods are and how to use them? This kind of casting is not needed in order to call this `childFunction`.

Comment: This *might* be an XY problem. You can definitely downcast using `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, but there are likely other language features or design patterns you could use instead that would lead to a cleaner solution. Virtual functions might be relevant in some cases; holding a separate container of derived class objects might be relevant in others; event driven mechanics, like the observer pattern, might be relevant in others; and so on. More details about the use case are needed to actually help make a decision, I think.